# Yosemite Boot Up USB

Tags: macos, osx-yosemite

I need to create a USB Boot Up containing the Yosemite Installer. All the methods i have found on the internet insist that i have the Yosemite.app installer, to create the USB before installing the OS. I don't have the installer in my applications folder it's been a while since i installed the Yosemite. How can i create the USB Boot up now since i don't have the Yosemite.app ? I tried to use a third party application like the DiskMAker application but it also needs that i have the installer.. Any Ideas?

Comment: Voting to close as this is not directly programming related.

Comment: @Abizern it is not directly related to programming but knowing the answer will make my work as a developer a lot easier since the country i'm in has poor connection and re-downloading the file is a pseudo-nightmare. So that's why i asked the experts, if i knew the answer i wouldn't ask the question

Comment: There are other SE sites where it is more appropriate to ask this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that there is no other way to do it without re-downloading the file once again from the app store. Maybe Apple should take care of that matter

Answer (score -2):

You should be able to redownload the *"Install Yosemite.app"* from the App Store even on a Mac running 10.10. The App Store will display a warning about Yosemite being already installed, but you can simply click "Continue".

Once downloaded, you can use any guide out there to create a USB Installer, for example [this one](http://macs.about.com/od/OS-X-Yosemite/ss/How-to-Make-a-Bootable-USB-Drive-of-the-OS-X-Yosemite-Installer.htm), which also talks about redownloading the Installer.